# "WHERE x IN y" clause with dapper and postgresql throwing 42601: syntax error at or near \"$1\"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, npgsql

I have an array of strings, and I'd like to have a query containing an IN clause, like:

```
"... WHERE t.name IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')..>"
```

Here's the final bit of my query, which contains a "where X in Y" clause:

```
...
left join genre_tag_band_join tj on hb.id = tj.band_id or ob.id = tj.band_id
left join genre_tags t on tj.genre_tag_id = t.id
inner join venues v on e.venue_id = v.id

where t.name IN @tagsParam...
```

I make a Dapper call like this

```
var shows = con.Query<Event, Band, Band, GenreTag, Venue, Event>(query, (e, hb, ob, gt, v) =>
{
    Event show;
    ...
    return e;
},
new { tagsParam = tagsArr}).AsQueryable();
```

where tagsArr is a string[].

I get exception:

> {"42601: syntax error at or near \"$1\""}

Comment: guessing that you have malformed data that you are querying here.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, you can't use IN to check whether a value is inside an array, you have to use the following PostgreSQL-specific syntax: `where t.name = ANY (@tagsParam)`. See the section 8.15.5 in the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html).

Comment: Hm, sill no luck when I do `...and t.name = ANY @tagsParam`. I think postgresql does support "IN": http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/. When I run a query like `...inner join venues v on e.venue_id = v.id                  
where
(e.date > current_date)
and t.name in ('foo')...` in pgadmin, it does work..

Comment: PostgreSQL supports IN, but not with array types - (1, 2) is not an array type. With the ANY syntax, can you try surrounding @tagParam with parentheses?

Comment: This is confusing because you normally expect Dapper to rewrite `where foo in (@array)` to `where foo in (@a1, @a2, ...) ` but it does not do that for PostgreSQL for some reason.

Comment: I totally lost faith in Postgres right now :D