# Dapper and Npgsql throws exception by use EXPLAIN with IN-clause and List<int>

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I try to fetch an execution plan from Postgresql via Npgsql and Dapper.

And versions of used software.

- .Net Framework 4.6.1
- ASP.NET WebAPI 2
- Postgresql 9.4
- Npgsql v3.0.5
- Dapper v1.42.0

---

Non-EXPLAIN query with IN-clause with List<int> can fetch rows.

`ex: SELECT 1 FROM banana WHERE banana_id IN @BananaIdList`

But with EXPLAIN query throws followed Npgsql.NpgsqlException *`42601: syntax error at or near \"$1\"`*.

`ex: EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM banana WHERE banana_id IN @BananaIdList`

---

Why EXPLAIN syntax with IN-clause causes NpgsqlException?

Can I fetch execution plan?

.

I wrote a simple program for reproduce.

Running on Console project and WebAPI2 throws same Exception.

```
public class BadQuery {

    public async Task Test() {
        const string Sql = "EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM banana WHERE banana_id IN @BananaIdList";

        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@BananaIdList", new List<int> {1, 2, 3});

        var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; Port=******; Database=******; User Id=******; Password=******;");
        conn.Open();

        var results = await conn.QueryAsync<string>(Sql, parameters); // throws NpgsqlException
    }

}
```

---

I found a similar question, but this question uses Array[].

["WHERE x IN y" clause with dapper and postgresql throwing 42601: syntax error at or near \"$1\"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193978/where-x-in-y-clause-with-dapper-and-postgresql-throwing-42601-syntax-error-at)

Thanks.

Comment: Fair question. I suspect that it is because it is trying to use array semantics rather than parameter expansion. Have you tried `where banana_id=any(:BananaIdList)` ?

Comment: I've tested it locally, and it seems to work the same (correctly) regardless of list or array - you *should* just have to change it to use the `any` syntax, as per the question you've linked to. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for reply @marc-gravell. I misunderstood query `in any(@ThemeIdList)`. So after changing to `= any(@ThemeIdList)`, probrems are resolved. Then, I think your replied reason is true.

Comment: And finally, I understood a specifications(now) that use Dapper with Npgsql. A non-EXPLAIN query can use `in @ParametersOfList`. But an EXPLAIN query can only use `= any(@ParametersOfList)`. 
I was mazed by these differences, and these are minor bugs I think.

Comment: Ugh... sorry, I found another reasons of probrem.
I wrote can use non-Explain query with `IN-clause with List<int>`, but can not use it _too_.
This is not a bug.

Comment: Why misunderstood this, I forgot that I use Glimpse.
And wrap `PgsqlConnection` by `GlimpseDbConnection`, and these program hiding on deep.
Then, Non-EXPLAIN queries are executed by `GlimpseDbConnection`, and EXPLAIN queries are executed by `PgsqlConnection`.

Now I found wrap `PgsqlConnection` by `GlimpseDbConnection`, it can use `IN-clause with List<int>`, but can not use `=any(List<int>)`.
These differences confuse me.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot that I use Glimpse.
And wrap `PgsqlConnection` by `GlimpseDbConnection`, these program hiding on deep.

I used two connections to avoid EXPLAIN queries being displayed on Glimpse,
Non-EXPLAIN queries are executed by `GlimpseDbConnection`,
and, EXPLAIN queries are executed by `PgsqlConnection`.

Now I found defference about below.

**PgsqlConnection**
 - Can not : `IN-clause with List<int>`
 - Can :`=any(List<int>)`

**GlimpseDbConnection (Include PgsqlConnection)**
 - Can : `IN-clause with List<int>`
 - Can not :`=any(List<int>)`

These differences confuse me.

So the answer is ***"MUST use `=any(List<T>)`"***.